# Is there attraction between positively charged glass rod and negatively charged silk cloth

Tags: electrostatics

I read the topic on electrostatics but i don't know the answer of above question. Similarly there is another question that Is there attraction between positively charged fur  and negatively charged ebonite rod.

Comment: There is an attraction between any two objects of opposite charge. The material is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is attraction between any two objects carrying opposite charge. The material carrying the charge is irrelevant. (As Chis points out)

Certain material get charged when rubbed with one another, this is known as charging by friction. The material with greater electron affinity picks up electrons from the other, acquiring a negative charge and leaving a positive charge. For example,  glass rod when rubbed against a silk cloth acquires a positive charge while the silk becomes negatively charged. Once the charges are distributed, we have attraction in accordance with Coulomb's law.